# Default.css is not loaded for openfaces

Tags: jsf, openfaces

I am getting title as error and it is asking

> Did you use head instead of h:head?

I started to use OpenFaces, add JAR to library, and add namespace

```
xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/"
```

I can see components working right but without styling.
I am using a tree, I can expand it but can not close it.

Should I add some css to somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suppose that you've used `<h:head>` tag in your xhtml page (and not the plain `<head>` tag), as the error message suggests...

Other than that there's nothing that you should do to make it work without this error (if you're using JSF 2.x based version of OpenFaces).

If you're using OpenFaces 3.0 release (with JSF 2.x) then there was a [bug](http://requests.openfaces.org/browse/OF-84) where this error was shown in some configurations despite having the `<h:head>` tag in the page. Try the current [nightly build](http://openfaces.org/downloads/) where this problem is fixed.

Comment: There is a message before the nightly build links: 'The packages of the nightly build are for information purposes only and not for immediate implementation in your projects.' Can i download and add jar libs to my project safely? Thanks very much for response.

Comment: In general, nightly builds are in most cases quite stable. But since they are prepared against an intermediate version of the library which is being in progress of development, there can be certain problems related to the on-going development. So they can be used but with caution (maybe some testing should be performed to ensure that it's Ok, etc., depending on the situation).